# Fill Screen with Overlay View in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed this [Blog](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/) to add Overlay View on my Camera Preview.

In background, Camera Preview is opened, and on the top of it there is overlay outer rectangle (in Fuchsia color) and circle shape inside.

But this overlay outer rectangle (in Fuchsia color) width & height is limited. It isn't covering the rest of outer space, so the remaining space is uncolored. I want to fill this "uncolored space" with overlay outer rectangle color aswell.

**CODE**

**.xml.cs**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3"
      x:Name="GridCameraPreview"
      IsVisible="True">
    <local:CameraPreview x:Name="CameraPreview"
                         Camera="Front"
                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         WidthRequest="300" />
    <local:CameraOverlayView x:Name="overlayView"
                             CameraOverlayOpacity="2"
                             Scale="360"
                             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <local:CameraOverlayView ShowOverlay="True"
                             CameraOverlayBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             CameraOverlayOpacity="0.5"
                             HeightRequest="175"
                             WidthRequest="175"
                             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</Grid>
```

[Overlay control class](https://gist.github.com/rdelrosario/9f4e4a9776108a5d60d9f41062afea9b#file-overlayview-cs)

[Native overlay view in Android](https://gist.github.com/rdelrosario/a4bfe241c42ed79facc91baab6e1966e#file-nativeoverlayview-cs)

```
namespace Mobile.App.Droid
{
    public class CameraNativeOverlayView : View
    {
        Bitmap windowFrame;

        float overlayOpacity = 0.5f;


        bool showOverlay = false;
        public bool ShowOverlay
        {
            get { return showOverlay; }
            set
            {
                bool repaint = !showOverlay;
                showOverlay = value;
                if (repaint)
                {
                    Redraw();
                }
            }
        }

        public float Opacity
        {
            get { return overlayOpacity; }
            set
            {
                overlayOpacity = value;
                Redraw();
            }
        }

        Color overlayColor = Color.Gray;
        public Color OverlayBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return overlayColor; }
            set
            {
                overlayColor = value;
                Redraw();

            }
        }

        CameraOverlayShape overlayShape = CameraOverlayShape.Circle;

        public CameraOverlayShape Shape
        {
            get { return overlayShape; }
            set
            {
                overlayShape = value;
                Redraw();

            }
        }

        public CameraNativeOverlayView(Context context, bool showOverlay = false) : base(context)
        {
            ShowOverlay = showOverlay;
            SetWillNotDraw(false);
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            if (ShowOverlay)
            {
                if (windowFrame == null)
                {
                    CreateWindowFrame();
                }
                canvas.DrawBitmap(windowFrame, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
        void Redraw()
        {
            if (ShowOverlay)
            {
                windowFrame?.Recycle();
                windowFrame = null;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        void CreateWindowFrame()
        {
            float width = this.Width;
            float height = this.Height;

            windowFrame = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame);
            Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias)
            {
                Color = OverlayBackgroundColor,
                Alpha = (int)(255 * Opacity)
            };

            RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

            osCanvas.DrawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

            paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));


            switch (Shape)
            {
                case CameraOverlayShape.Circle:

                    float radius = Math.Min(width, height) * 0.45f;
                    osCanvas.DrawCircle(width / 2, (height / 2), radius, paint);

                    break;
                default:

                    Path path = new Path();
                    // Starting point
                    path.MoveTo(width / 2, height / 5);

                    // Upper left path
                    path.CubicTo(5 * width / 14, 0,
                            0, height / 15,
                            width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

                    // Lower left path
                    path.CubicTo(width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
                            3 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
                            width / 2, height);

                    // Lower right path
                    path.CubicTo(4 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
                            13 * width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
                            27 * width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

                    // Upper right path
                    path.CubicTo(width, height / 15,
                            9 * width / 14, 0,
                            width / 2, height / 5);

                    osCanvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            windowFrame?.Recycle();
            windowFrame = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: have no idea regrading native overlay. Just another suggestion. What if you created a camera preview and use it inside xaml and add overlay using semi transparent frame there?

Comment: You can easily create camerapreview with xamarin community toolkit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview

Comment: thanks @Anand, actually as in above added screenshot, Camera Preview is working fine.. I wanted to add overlay view which has a Circle Shape in the middle, and outer space of that Circle has to fill the rest of screen. I used Pancake view, box view, frame everything, nothing helped to achieve this, but then I found this article https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/ .. now, I'm stuck with this small little addition, and don't know how to do it..

Comment: Need more code. "something" must determine the rectangle that you are unable to draw outside of.  In `CreateWindowFrame`, what does `this` refer to? `this` must either live inside some larger view, OR it must have margins that create that black area. Your problem isn't in the code shown. Also, the code (CreateWindowFrame) shown: is that Android-specific, or is it cross-platform?

Comment: thanks for your response. I added code above for view and also complete code for Native Overlay page, please have a look.. `CreateWindowFrame()` is android-specific. full sample source code https://github.com/CrossGeeks/OverlaySample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run the project in the link you provided, it works fine, the overlay view fills screen as expected:

[image]

Make sure overlay view totally covers the CameraPreview , we can place them into a same row / column in a Grid, and set the `Scale` as `1`.

## Update

#### OverlayView

Add a new BindableProperty named `ShapeScaleProperty` in `OverlayView` .

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ShapeScaleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      propertyName: nameof(ShapeScale),
      returnType: typeof(double),
      declaringType: typeof(OverlayView),
      defaultValue: 1.0,
      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public double ShapeScale
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ShapeScaleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShapeScaleProperty, value); }
        }
```

#### MainPage

Change `Scale` to `ShapeScale` in xaml

```
<controls:OverlayView 
Shape="Heart" 
Grid.Row="0" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
x:Name="overlayView" 
OverlayOpacity="{Binding Path=Value, Source={x:Reference Name=slider3}}"  
ShapeScale="{Binding Path=Value, Source={x:Reference Name=slider2}}"  //this line
HeightRequest="400" 
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

#### NativeOverlayView in android project

Add a new property `ShapeScale`

```
 double shapeScale = 1f;
        public double ShapeScale
        {
            get { return shapeScale; }
            set
            {              
                if (shapeScale != value)
                {
                    Redraw();
                }
                shapeScale = value;
            }
        }
```

`CreateWindowFrame` method

```
void CreateWindowFrame()
        {
            float width = this.Width;
            float height = this.Height;
          
            windowFrame = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame);
            Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias)
            {
                Color = OverlayBackgroundColor,
                Alpha = (int)(255 * Opacity)
            };

            RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

            osCanvas.DrawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

            paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));



            float shapeWidth = (float)(width * shapeScale);
            float shapeHeight = (float)(height * shapeScale);

            switch (Shape)
            {


                case OverlayShape.Circle:
                    float radius = (Math.Min(shapeWidth, shapeHeight) * 0.45f);
                    osCanvas.DrawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, paint);

                    break;
                default:

                    Path path = new Path();
                    // Starting point
                    path.MoveTo(shapeWidth / 2, shapeHeight / 5);

                    // Upper left path
                    path.CubicTo(5 * shapeWidth / 14, 0,
                            0, shapeHeight / 15,
                            shapeWidth / 28, 2 * shapeHeight / 5);

                    // Lower left path
                    path.CubicTo(shapeWidth / 14, 2 * shapeHeight / 3,
                            3 * shapeWidth / 7, 5 * shapeHeight / 6,
                            shapeWidth / 2, shapeHeight);

                    // Lower right path
                    path.CubicTo(4 * shapeWidth / 7, 5 * shapeHeight / 6,
                            13 * shapeWidth / 14, 2 * shapeHeight / 3,
                            27 * shapeWidth / 28, 2 * shapeHeight / 5);

                    // Upper right path
                    path.CubicTo(shapeWidth, shapeHeight / 15,
                            9 * shapeWidth / 14, 0,
                            shapeWidth / 2, shapeHeight / 5);



                    path.Offset(width/2- shapeWidth/2 , height/2 - shapeHeight/2);

                    osCanvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
                    break;
            }


        }
```

#### OverlayViewRenderer

in `OnElementPropertyChanged` method , add the following code

```
   else if (e.PropertyName == OverlayView.ShapeScaleProperty.PropertyName)
   {
        Control.ShapeScale = Element.ShapeScale;
   }
```

Comment: thanks for response.. I added code above for the view, kindly have a look.. actually the Circle is small in my app, so, when I make it smaller, the outer rectangle also become smaller.. please, try that

Comment: Could you provide a basic project which could reproduce the issue ?  You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Kinldy visit this page, https://github.com/CrossGeeks/OverlaySample, and in Readme page, there will be a gif, in that gif, when the scale is increased or decreased, the outer rectangle (overlay), is also increasing decreasing.. can I make it constant and fit on the screen?

Comment: I want that when I increase / decrease scale through cursose, the shape (circle, heart) should should increase/decrease too, but the outer rectangle (overlay), has to fill the rest of the screen..

Comment: You just want to increase / decrease  the shape but not the  outer rectangle ?

Comment: YES!!!.. outer rectangle has to fill the screen no matter the size of inside shape (circle)..

Comment: Okay , I understand , will post the solution later if I figure out it .

Comment: thanks for the solution, I pasted your code in my project nothing changed..

Comment: Did you add the code based on the project : https://github.com/CrossGeeks/OverlaySample ?

Comment: yes.. but view page is a bit different, in the question I added that section.

Comment: I solved the problem.. actually, in my project their isn't any slider, and the value of `ShapeScale` is changed through `Binding`.. but there is a default value in `NativeOverlayView`, so I used `SecureStorage` as a global variable to get the value from... I've multiple pages, where the `ShapeScale` values has to be different, this approach helped me, but set the value in every page `OnAppearing()` function.